# How can I fix this output?

Tags: dynamic, output-formatting, inputfield

The following segment of code is part of a project I am making and therefore I cannot show all the code. I hope the one below is enough.

The input is

```
Panel[DynamicModule[var, InputField[Dynamic[var], String]]]
```

while the output is

[image]

which in thid case displays DynamicModule[var,] that is  not wanted. How would I fix this? I want to add that I want to keep the same functions used above.

Also, how would I put text next to the input field? Thank you.

Comment: Use `DynamicModule[{var}, ...]` instead.

Comment: @CarlWoll this does seem to fix the problem but now when I enter a word and press enter nothing happens. Instead, it should evaluate the command as it did without this fix.

Comment: @DMH16 It still does but if you need the variable outside of `DynamicModule` you will need an assignment in `Dynamic[globVar = var]`

Comment: @Coolwater **Set::write: Tag Set in globVar=FE`var$$22 is Protected.**. This is the error message I get. Do you know why this happens? I know that it his hard to not be able to work with the actual code and that therefore your help is limited.

Comment: @DMH16 `Dynamic[var, (var = globVar = #) &]` works, but I don't understand why the `Dynamic[globVar = var]` doesn't :/

Comment: @Coolwater because `Set` is not `Flat` and `(x = y) = 5` is not the same as `x = y = 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{var = "Type here"},
  InputField[Dynamic[var], String]]]
```

or, for a version with a variable `text` that can be inspected

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{var = "Type here"},
  InputField[Dynamic[var, (text = var = #) &], String],
  Initialization :> (text = var)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to add a comment above. Try this... Also, note that Modules and Dynamic Modules are like Objects and the variables such as 'var' is only valid inside the Module

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{var}, Grid[{{InputField[Dynamic[var], String],Dynamic[var]}}]]]
```

We can just include Panel inside the Module

```
DynamicModule[{var}, Panel[InputField[Dynamic[var], String],Dynamic[var]]]
```

All you do is tab whenever you fill the input field